# Get file path using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background**

I have written a terminal-based installer for my application in Python and now I am trying to build a web-based GUI for the installer in React that users will run locally, i.e., I will distribute the web app as part of the package. I want my GUI to save the user-defined paths to a file that my Python backend will then read.

**What I tried**

I tried using `<input type="file"/>`, but this simply gives me the name of the file. I then searched for other solutions but I read that browsers don't allow access to the file system for security reasons. I also read that I can use Electron to access the file system, so this is my plan B.

**The bottom line**

Is it possible for a user to specify a file path in the web app using a browse-box widget (so without actually typing it in) in React without using Electron? If so, how?

Comment: I don't think that would be possible with only browser and not electron for the same security reason as mentioned by you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - it seems like a longshot but I was hoping that there might be a workaround if the user knows precisely what they are doing (they are explicitly defining the path), or if they are running the app locally.

Comment: File inputs will not work. The best you can do is provide user a text input where they can enter something like `C:/path/to/file.py`, otherwise what you can do is read the file object in js (without Electron, with normal file Input) and pass the whole object to python instead of a path.